# An email-friendly way to drop horizontal columns into vertical on mobile screens (no <div>s and no min-width)

Tags: html, responsive-design, html-email

I have realized that neither using `<div>`s nor having a `min-width` attribute on an email will lead to good results. I have the following code. The alignment for the three horizontal columns work well on desktop screens but there is still no guarantee for different sizes. As I open the email on my iPhone the screen tries to adjust and I the alignment no longer looks good.

Here is what I get on my iPhone:
[image]

And here is the code that generates this:

```
<table style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #f99f11;" valign="top">

        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td colspan="5">
            <h2>
              Ditt medlemskap</h2>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff; width: 30%" valign="top">
            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0;">
              R&auml;tta dina uppgifter</h3>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff; width: 30%" valign="top">
            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0;">
              Tipsa oss om<br>
              ny medlem</h3>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff; width: 30%" valign="top">
            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0;">
              Utvecklas<br>
              som chef</h3>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff;" valign="top">
            <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/watch.png" style="height: auto; width: 100%; display: block;"></td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff;" valign="top">
            <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/watch.png" style="height: auto; width: 100%; display: block;"></td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff;" valign="top">
            <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/watch.png" style="height: auto; width: 100%; display: block;"></td>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td style="background-color: #fff" valign="top">
            Det &auml;r viktigt att vi har r&auml;tt uppgifter om dig. Logga in och &auml;ndra h&auml;r.</td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td style="background-color: #fff" valign="top">
            Vet du n&aring;gon som &auml;nnu inte &auml;r medlem? Tipsa oss!</td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td style="background-color: #fff" valign="top">
            Ta del av ett stort utbud av kostnadsfria kurser och seminarier!</td>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="30px">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30px">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, to clear any doubts. I want the horizontal block to turn into a stack in case the screen is under a specified size. This size is already declared in the template code CSS on which this code sits on. It resides on a separate file.

**N.B.** Knowing this is an HTML email, I want to avoid using `<div>`s and we are limited to `<table>`s. No `min-width` as Outlook is incompatible with them. The styling code are better kept inside HTML tags.

Comment: You said you tried div's is that for hybrid coding? Hybrid can break columns into rows without media queries. You can then use media queries to make it look good.

Answer (score -1):

The layout of your 3 columns will need adjusting but you can easily make them stack with CSS and a media query.

Here's an example below of how I would make a 3 column layout using `th` elements.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <!-- 1st column -->
    <th class="stack" style="background-color: #ffffff;" valign="top">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td> <!-- H3--> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <!-- IMAGE --></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <!-- COPY --></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </th>
    <!-- IF YOU WANT A GAP BETWEEN TH -->
    <th width="20" style="width:20px" class="hide"></th>
    <!-- 2nd column -->
    <th class="stack" style="background-color: #ffffff;" valign="top"></th>
    <!-- IF YOU WANT A GAP BETWEEN TH -->
    <th width="20" style="width:20px" class="hide"></th>
    <!-- 3rd column -->
    <th class="stack" style="background-color: #ffffff;" valign="top"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This media query in your styles will stack the `th` elements on mobile views. You'll be telling the `th` with content to expaned full width and force them to stack and also hiding any empty spacer `th`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .stack {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .hide {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, could you be slightly more concrete? I applied your code and now almost nothing scales.